# iPad SplitViewController usage - what is the design concept re not being allowed to push a SplitViewController after you already have a split view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, storyboard

As I'm just starting to develop an iPad application & have started getting used to UISplitViewController (within Storyboard).  The immediate issue I'm hitting is that I'm getting errors as I try to jump from one splitViewController to another, and getting errors such as:

- "Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller " and
- "Application tried to present a Split View Controllers modall".

Would appreciate some feedback in terms of laying out an iPad app here - my thinking (which perhaps is flawed) was as follows:  Have an app with (a) list of views the user can select, (b) list of view items for a particular view, call them Items, and (c) Item Details.   All are TableViews...   Was going to have the concept of:

- (a) 1st SplitViewController - has ViewList on left hand side and Items on right hand side, and
- (b) 2nd SplitViewController- has ItemsList on left hand side and Item Details on right hand side
- So you see if on (a) you click on an Item in the right hand pane, this would trigger the user then seeing a new overall view with (b) Items on the left, with the one pressed highlighted and the details for this item on the right.   Effectively sliding the views across one to the left if you know what I mean...

This doesn't seem to be possible via pushing a new SplitViewController onto an existing one? Questions I am pondering are:

- a) Is my requirements concept above ok for an iPad app?  If not how would you do this?
- b) If yes, how would you implement these?  Do you have to stick with the same splitViewController and programmatically swap out the tableViewControllers allocated to it, in which case you kind of lose the readability of the page flow using the Storyboard approach I'm using in XCode 4.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, according to iOS guidelines a SplitViewController should be the root view controller of application. So legally you cannot push split View Controller on navigation controller.
 However, you can design your own splitview according to your requirement try following links

This link might be helpful

https://github.com/grgcombs/IntelligentSplitViewController

https://github.com/SlavaBushtruk/APSplitViewController

OR

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController